# Как вызвать диалоговое сообщение из EditTExt

Tags: android, android-edittext

У меня есть `EditText`. При нажатии кнопки, если `EditText` пустой, он становится красным и должен требовать ввести в него что-то. Как вызвать сообщение, как на фото или скажите, как оно называется:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так пробовали `EditText.setError("WTF?!");`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, нет :).

Comment: В библиотеку *support:design* входит виджет `TextInputLayout`, который несколько расширяет возможности `EditText`. [Пример](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/textinputlayout/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для показа сообщения об ошибке есть метод `setError(String error)`

```
editText.setError("WTF?!");
```

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы не просто круг появлялся, а еще и сообщение выскакивало? Сразу.

Comment: Хз, погуглите - я вот ответ на вопрос изначальный гуглом секунд за 45 нашёл.

Comment: В интернетах наоборот жалуются, что текст не убрать... Поиграйтесь с фокусом editText. Похоже, он у вас не в фокусе, когда вы ошибку на нём вызываете.

Comment: А можно сделать так, чтобы оно раскрывалось при нажатии на круг и так же закрывалось? Или это вынести в отдельный вопрос?

Comment: Можно. Носкорее всего для этого надо свой едиттекст делать и переопоеделять/назначать слушатель клика на кружок. Воядли есть стандартный средства. Такчто пилите вопрос новый)

Comment: Теперь несколько экранов переделывать. Я про эти кружочки вспомнил только тогда, когда начал делать второй ввод на другом экране...

Comment: Думаю проще место под сообщение оставить) Спокойной ночи)

Comment: Проблема в том, что так нельзя. Спокойной, до завтрашней ночи! :D